# Automating Fortify SSC report

Tags: automation, fortify

I'm using jenkin to automate Fortify sca scan. I can only automate clean, translate, scan and upload FPR file to SSC. Can someone please let me know how can I automate report generation for every upload and emailing it directly to the developers in CI CD pipeline?

Comment: Fortify has a set of REST APIs. See if you can find an API to download the report.

Answer (score 0):

The fortify jenkins plugin returns the result back to Jenkins. On the left panel of your job, you could find the link to Fortify Assessment and click it to open the detail of the issue list and related sourcecode.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With each installation of Fortify SCA, it comes with a BIRTReportGenerator tool, you can use it after the scan is complete to injest the FPR file and generate a PDF of template type Developer Workbook for your developers to download and read.

However, if you want to have a report consisting of suppressed issues you have to trigger a FPR download from Fortify SSC and convert that FPR to a PDF with the same tool.